# Getting inserted row on if/-then-else statement

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

When I use an if-then-else to check if a record exists then call the last insert using `$pdocon->lastInsertId()` it does not return the inserted row. For example:

```
if exists(
    SELECT first_name FROM `my_table` 
            WHERE first_name = 'adam'
    ) 
    then 
        SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE first_name = 'adam'
    else 
        INSERT INTO my_table
        (first_name) 
        values
        ('adam')
    END IF;
```

This (simplified) code checks to see if a record exists. If it does exist, it grabs the info. If it does not exist it inserts it. That part all works fine, the problem comes in when I try to get the inserted ID from a name the doesn't exist (returns a 0 as lastInsertId).

Is there a practical way around this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that names are not duplicated, then you should define a unique index or constraint on the column:

```
alter table t add unique constraint unq_my_table_first_name unique (first_name);
```

Then you can use the following trick to get the correct id using `last_insert_id()`:

```
insert into mytable (first_name)
    values ('Adam')
    on duplicate key update id = last_insert_id(id);
```

You can then use:

```
select last_insert_id()
```

to get the last insert id regardless of whether the statement was an `update` or `insert`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7174ab08b08e8c7312b7e4d9c1d81739) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I do have a unique constraint already on the table (my example is a simplified version just to show the problem without having a ton of superfluous columns, etc). The actual code that I'm using pulls a lot more info and checks against other POST variables, COOKIES, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First the question should not have PHP tag because PHP doesn't have `if-then-else` conditional statement that's a Visual Basic conditional statement. Nevertheless an `if-else` can handle this with you using the right SQL query, SQL already provides a query that solves the issue above i.e. to check for the existence of a record and that should help.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE condition);
```

Comment: I'm using the php to get the last inserted ID via `$pdocon->lastInsertId()`

Comment: The `if/then/else` is T-SQL, not VB.NET - please don't edit questions which change them fundamentally. And even if it was .NET how would you tell it was VB not C#? Please be careful with your edits!

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking in the future, another user posted the answer but then deleted it. The correct way to accomplish this is:

```
if exists(
    SELECT first_name FROM `my_table` 
            WHERE first_name = 'adam'
    ) 
    then 
        SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE first_name = 'adam'
    else 
        INSERT INTO my_table
        (first_name) 
        values
        ('adam');
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as inserted;
    END IF;
```